# straight quotes to curly quotes

Tags: php, javascript, css

Is there a way to convert straight quotes to curly quotes on a page using CSS?

' = straight quote

“ = curly quote

if not, or javascript? Like is there a javascript that can convert all straight quotes on a page to curly quotes?

If not, how do we do so in php?

Comment: Can you show what you mean by "straight" and "curly" exactly?

Comment: Use any text editor and do a Find & Replace of the unicode versions with simple versions of quotes. Or do you need to automate something because you will often be receiving CSS files with unicode quotes instead of the correct simple quote? (")

Comment: @Pekka I guess he means to convert `""` to `“”`.

Comment: See https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenquotes/tree/main/src/main/java/com/whitemagicsoftware/keenquotes for a Java-based solution, which should port to PHP with some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use str_replace() if you can edit the php file. Just use the following syntax

```
str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ]);
```

ex: `str_replace (' " ', ' ” ', $php_output);`

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can do it like that:

```
<script>
    function replace(node) {
        if (node.childNodes === undefined) {
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
            var child = node.childNodes[i];
            if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                child.data = child.data.replace(/"/g, '“');
            }

            replace(child);
        }
    }
    replace(document.body);
</script>
```

Probably you should modify this code in that way it'll close opened quote.

Answer (score 0):

curly quotes are not the same characters as straight quotes.

Therefore as long as you actually type the curly quotes instead of the straight ones they will appear like that on your page.